# Why should the image screen be placed at fourth focal plane in 4f setup?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

They call it the 4f setup. But when the image coming from the second lens is anyway collimated, why is it necessary to place the image screen at the fourth focal plane?

Answer (score 1):

If you just have collimated light going into the system and nothing at the image plane then, yes, there will be nothing but collimated light coming out of the last lens and you could put the image screen where ever you want (and not see an image anywhere).  But, if there is something at the "input" plane it scatters the incoming collimated light and its image is focused (only) at the fourth focal plane.  [FIGURE 11.8](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FYmZBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=4f%20setup%20collimated&source=bl&ots=CtomG39q_8&sig=2b4kjKGSgPc0RlN6CRghQ1fuDNI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG8-Cyz-vMAhUHVFIKHcMnAYoQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=4f%20setup%20collimated&f=false) here might help.

Comment: I had to click "View All", then "Go" in order to see the page; it is a good illustration.